# CheckerBoard JPanel

Tags: java, user-interface, loops

I have this for a checker board and I connected it to a JPanel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class CheckerBoard extends JFrame
{

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
  int row;
  int col;
  int x;
  int y;

  for ( row = 0;  row < 9;  row++ )
  {
     for ( col = 0;  col < 8;  col++)
     {
        x = col * 22;
        y = row * 22;
         if ( (row % 2) == (col % 2) )
           g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
           g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.fillRect(x, y, 22, 22);
     }
  }
 }
```

This is the Connceted JPanel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
public class JFRAME
{   public static void main() 
    {

        CheckerBoard check = new CheckerBoard();
        check.setTitle("CheckerBoard");
        check.setSize(180, 200);
        check.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        check.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I compile the Jpanel it says "cannot find symbol-variable EXIT_ON_CLOSE"

Im trying to make an 8 by 8 checker board that prompts the user for the number of rows and columns of the board before displaying them.

Comment: Also, don't draw directly on the JFrame but rather within the paintComponent method of a JPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.  It's good that you're trying to provide some context.  However, in this case, the answer appears to just be:
You need WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE instead of just EXIT_ON_CLOSE

Comment: (Note that per answer in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799940/jframe-exit-on-close-java, WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE is prefered to JFRAME.EXIT_ON_CLOSE but they're both the same integer)  Also... does that solve your question, or was there another issue beyond the compile error?

Answer (score 2):

`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is actually a `public static final int` field defined in `JFrame`, this means you need to use `JFrame` to reference it, like `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`

Or you could add `import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;` to your import statements

## Updated...

As pointed out by Hovercraft, you shouldn't be overriding `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, there are lots of reasons for this, but it's generally going to give you lots of trouble as your application complexity grows.

Instead, start with a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method, making sure you call `super.paintComponent` first.  Then, simply add this to what ever container you want to use.

Have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Best answer. Also, she shouldn't be drawing directly on the JFrame as she's trying to do.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks, I'll update when I have some more time

Answer (score 0):

Should be `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` And please don't call your class `JFRAME` that is just messed up!