# JFrame has no close window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

For some reason my JFrame doesn't have a close button? I tried changing the code but it didn't seem to work.

```
public NewJFrame()
{
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setVisible(true);


    initComponents();

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(NewJFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    int x = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth();
    int y = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight();
    this.setSize(x,y);
}
```

Comment: Try resizing it manually with mouse - may be close button is just hidden

Comment: Nope I can't resize the JFrame.

Comment: Similar questions have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799940/jframe-exit-on-close-java)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The close button is one of the decorations you removed with

```
this.setUndecorated(true);
```

If you want it back you'll have to remove this line or create one of your own.